# how to use Case Expression in Derived Column in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, business-intelligence

I have got file Data like this

```
Val     type 
7000    Main
7000.1  Spouse
7000.2  Child
7000.3  Child
7000.4  Child
8000    main
8000.1  Spouse
```

In Sql I have written Case Condition

```
Select CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(val,CHARINDEX('.',val))= 0 THEN 'main'
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(val,CHARINDEX('.',val))= 1 THEN 'Spouse'
ELSE 'Child'
```

So it will give 
Main for not having Decimal values 
and 1 for Spouse and Rest are child
But how can I write the same condition for Derived Column in SSIS package

Comment: That's case expressions, not case statements...

Comment: Sorry Typo Mistake I will modify @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this.

```
FINDSTRING(val,".",1) == NULL(DT_WSTR,10) ? "Main" : SUBSTRING(val,FINDSTRING(val,".",1)+1,1) == "1" ? "Spouse" : "Child"
```